# BitLocker Windows 10 key ID match, but password not

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, encryption, bitlocker

I'm using Windows 10 on a Windows Surface device. I'm unable to recover a data on my drive which was encrypted with a BitLocker. Here's what I did:

1. I have 2 partitions, C: (OS), D: (data), E: (data) - removable disc
2. I've made a copy of a drive D: with FTK Imager v 3.1.1 and saved the image on a removable drive E:
3. I encrypted the removable drive E: with a BitLocker and save the recovery password in a Microsoft cloud
4. I removed the E: drive from my Windows Surface Device
5. I connected the E: device again, and tried to recover the data with a recovery key. The id's of the key's matches, but the BitLocker says that the password is wrong.

What might be the cause here?

Comment: "What might be the cause here?" - You royally screwed up; Surface devices have a TPM, Bitlocker encrypted your partition using the TPM; If the recovery password isn't working then you are out of luck.  Are you using Bitlocker or Device Encryption, similar features, but not exactly the same.

Comment: @Ramhound: What is the difference between them? Can anything can be done now? Because I do not understand why it does not work now. IDs match but the password is bad at least windows says so.

Comment: Device encryption can be enabled on any version of Windows 8, Windows 8.1, or Windows 10.  Device Encryption typically was enabled by default on tablets. Bitlocker is limited to Professional+

Comment: @Ramhound: Ok but i still do not understand why the password does not work when the ID's of the keys match each other.